# Javafx Choicebox - how to check if selected/activated

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a simple app using JavaFX.

I want to make a Choicebox, and when the Choicebox is activated - meaning if any value is selected - I want the code to progress.

this is working:

```
if ( choicebox.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){ DO SOMETHING }
```

why does the opposite not work? :

```
if (! choicebox.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){ DO SOMETHING }
```

EDIT: 
I have two layouts. One represents the choicebox and one that represents a set of checkboxes. What I want to accomplish is that the checkboxes should only appear WHEN the choicebox is activated / a value is selected.

```
    if (! choicebox.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){
    secondLayout.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: could you provide us example?

Comment: I have made an edit! Hope it makes sense.

Comment: are you sure that second layout will be re-drawn after you set it visible? Are you sure that **any** code in `if` statement will not run? try to add log/pop-up

Comment: how do you want it to be specific,  because there is selectedItem in your selectionModel, why not use it? infact you could use listeners, thats way easier you will have a boolean "newValue" and you can run your condition check on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
ChoiceBox<String> cb = new ChoiceBox(....);    
secondLayout.visibleProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> cb.getValue() != null, cb.valueProperty()));
```

As an alternative you can do:

```
secondLayout.visibleProperty().bind(Bindings.isNotNull(cb.valueProperty()));
```

Comment: So awesome!! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Awesome code!